Is there a way to have multiple y-axes in a stacked column chart in Powerbi?
I want to create a stacked column chart with multiple Y axes in the chart that are represented as columns.
I am aware that you can do a combined chart in Powerbi, but it only allows for the second axis to be represented by a line.
I also tried using the third party package "Multiple Axes Chart - XViz" but I need to pay for the package to get all the features. Moreover, when creating a chart using the package it does not allow me to display all the axes groups at the bottom. For example, I want to display "Year", "Region", and "Sourcing Area" but it only displays "Sourcing area". It also does not allow me to add gridlines at the bottom to separate the different regions clearly, nor arrange it by region for some reason.

Not sure what type of data you're working on, you can try a different visual like a Stacked & Line chart or you can play with the Legend and see if that will break down your data the way you want it. I personally use the latter often when I want to break down a Total Value down to its category.

I work with cost of production. As far as I can see, the only combined charts are line and column, never column and column with double axes
